# inner html scope not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view that looks like this

```
<div data-search-filters>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Filters</legend>
    <div id="filters">
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-wrapper">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="filter-add" value="Add Filter" />
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-ng-click="quotCtrl.applyFilters()">Apply Filters</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<!-- hidden templates -->
<div class="templates">
    <div class="template filter-chooser">
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger filter-remover" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        <!--<input type="button" class="filter-remover" value="X" />-->

        <select name="filter" class="filter-type">
            <option value="" data-template-type="" selected="selected">Choose a filter</option>
            <option value="rfqno" data-template-type="template-rfqno">Request No.</option>
            <option value="status" data-template-type="template-status">Status</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="template template-rfqno">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="quotCtrl.filters.rfqno" />
    </div>

    <div class="template template-status">
        <select
                class="form-control"
                data-ng-click="quotCtrl.getLOVs('QuoteStatus','quoteStatuses', {'response':'quotestatus_id&name','placeholder':'QuoteStatusHolder'})"
                data-ng-options="quoteStatus.quotestatus_id as quoteStatus.name for quoteStatus in quotCtrl.container['quoteStatuses']"
                data-ng-model="quotCtrl.filters.status">
            <option value="">{{quotCtrl.container['QuoteStatusHolder'] || 'Select quote status...'}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have a directive that is used to dynamically add a template to the id=filters like so:

```
function searchFilters($compile, $parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A'
    , transclude: true
    , template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    , link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var $filters = element.find('#filters');
        var templatesAvailable = element.find('.template', '.templates').not('.filter-chooser').length;

        element.find('#filter-add').on('click', function (e) {

            // Check if the button was pressed before selecting a filter
            if ($filters.find('.template:last .filter-type').val() === '') {
                return;
            }

            // Find filters already in use
            var filterInUse = $filters
                .children()
                .map(function() {
                    return angular.element(this)
                        .children('.template')
                        .attr('class')
                        .match(/\b(template-.+?)\b/g)[0];
                })
                .get();

            // All the filters available are already in use
            if (filterInUse.length === templatesAvailable) {
                return;
            }

            var $filterChooser = angular.element('div.template.filter-chooser')
                .clone()
                .removeClass('filter-chooser')
                .addClass('filter');

            // Remove filters already in use
            $filterChooser
                .find('option[data-template-type]')
                .filter(function() {
                    return filterInUse.indexOf(angular.element(this).data('template-type')) >= 0;
                })
                .remove();
            //$parse($filterChooser.appendTo($filters))(scope);
            $filterChooser.appendTo($filters)
        }).click();
        element.find('#filters').on('change', '.filter-type', function() {
                var $this = angular.element(this)
                var $filter = $this.closest('.filter');
                var filterType = $this.find(':selected').data('template-type');

                $('.qualifier', $filter).remove();
                $('div.template.' + filterType)
                    .clone()
                    .addClass('qualifier')
                    .appendTo($filter);
                $this.find('option[value=""]').remove();

            }).on('click', '.filter-remover', function() {
                angular.element(this).closest('.filter').remove();
            });
    }
};
```

}

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('searchFilters', searchFilters);

The challenge is that the directive works fine but the data-ng-click="quotCtrl.getLOVs('QuoteStatus','quoteStatuses', {'response':'quotestatus_id&name','placeholder':'QuoteStatusHolder'})" inside the select that is dynamically added does not work ......even when I add a $watch like so

```
        scope.$watch(function() { return $filters.contents() }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(oldValue)
            console.log(newValue)
        }, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! all I needed to do was to compile the variables inside
    **element.find('#filters').on('change', '.filter-type', function() {** 
So that I have :
    *var temp = $compile($('div.template.' + filterType).clone().addClass('qualifier'))(scope)
                temp.appendTo($filter);*

This complile function and its nuances...!!!!